# React Router on refresh with API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am currently working on a weather app constructed with react-create-app that works on React Router to show data for 5 different days. Each day (presented in a box) is a Link that redirects the second component to it specifically so that it can show more detailed data for the specific day.

I have a function that generates the data for each tile:

```
    generateTileData() {
    const weatherData = this.state.data;
    if (!weatherData) return null;
    let days = [];

    const newData = [...weatherData].filter(day => {
      let dateFromAPI = moment.unix(day.dt).date();
      if (days.indexOf(dateFromAPI) > -1) {
        return false;
      } else {
        days.push(dateFromAPI);
        return true;
      }
    });
    // console.log(days)

    return newData.map((day, item) => {
      const dateId = day.dt;
      return (
        <Link to={`/w/${dateId}`}>
          <WeatherTile key={day.dt} index={item} {...day} date={day.dt_txt} />
        </Link>
      );
    });
  }
```

That then is being rendered:

```
       <HashRouter>
          <React.Fragment>
            <div className="columns is-gapless tiles">
              {this.generateTileData()}
            </div>
          {weatherData && <Route exact path="/w/:dateId" render={({ match }) => <Weather data={weatherData} day={[...weatherData].find(day => day.dt == match.params.dateId)} />} />}
         </React.Fragment>
        </HashRouter>
```

The problem is that as I am fetching the data (through a form) only after the user inputs it, when I accidentally refresh the page, the application does not know where the data comes from and thus gives me a nice error that it cannot read the property main of undefined (as in my Weather component:

```
const Weather = ({ day }) => {
  console.log(day);
  const data = day;

  return (
    <div className="info">
      <p>{data.main.temp}</p>
      <p>{data.main.humidity}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is there any way that I can either prevent the user from refreshing or by default redirecting the user on refresh to the main page (that would be path="/")?

Comment: One strategy is to add something like `refresh: true` to your state. When the data is returned form the api call, set refresh to false. When it's true, though, you can display a message or a button that instructs the user to visit the form to submit data. So when the page is refreshed, you'll see the message instead of an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways I think you could go about getting around this issue. One way would be how @Pat Mellon described and to add a refresh state and redirect should it be true or false (however you want to build the logic).

You could also add in some default logic, which is more of a 'React' way of doing things. For instance, if there is no user info being seen by the app, simply output some example weather.

Up next would to be adding in url logic and sticking your user data into the url itself. Kind of like an API call, the app would look at the url and not the state to pull information to display. (Look at [URI.js](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) for a nice way of doing this)

Another way that might be a little more UX friendly is to persist the data from the form into the user's [local storage](https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_webstorage.asp). Using this method would allow you to maintain the data and use it even if the page is refreshed, closed, computer is restarted, etc. The only caveat is remembering to clear the user's local storage (and more importantly, the information that you saved and not that of other websites) if the user is to ever re-enter information into your form.

Lot's of fun ways to untangle this issue, and I'm sure plenty more than the four I've listed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I went with localStorage and it works like a charm:)

Comment: Glad I could help!